# Rescuscitaton of "Values of c for which the given quotient ring is a field."

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, polynomial-rings

This question is an attempt to resuscitate [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720362/values-of-c-for-which-the-given-quotient-ring-is-a-field), which was recently deleted by its author for reasons unknown to Yours Truly.

The question runs as follows:  given the polynomial

$X^3 + 3X^2 + cX + 3 \in \Bbb F_5[X], \tag 1$

find all

$c \in \Bbb F_5 \tag 2$

such that $F_5[X]/(X^3 + 3X^2 + cX + 3)$ is a field.

Various approaches to this problem have been made in the linked citing; my own solution is presented below in my answer.

***Note Added in Edit, Monday 15 June 2020 6:53 PM PST:***  In light of some of the comments, I would like to address the issue of differences/similarities between this question and the one linked in the above. ***End of Note.***

Comment: The deleted question has since been reopened.  For future reference, it is generally considered bad form for a user to delete a question after receiving an answer.  If you see this happen in the future, please consider bringing it up in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured), or posting an answer in the [Reopen / Undelete thread on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/).  This should limit the amount of duplication.

Comment: For the record, I was made aware of this thread and the earlier deleted thread because they were mentioned in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54670794#54670794).

Comment: @XanderHenderson:  Yes I saw that it was re-opened after I posted my variant.  I should probably edit a few words into  my question explaining any differences.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$X^3 + 3X^2 + 3cX + 3 \in \Bbb F_5 \tag 1$

is a cubic polynomial, it is reducible if and only if it has a linear factor, i.e., if and only if it is possessed of a root in $\Bbb F_5$.  We may evaluate this polynomial on the elements of $\Bbb F_5$ to determine the values of $c$ for which a zero exists.  Setting

$p(X, c) = X^3 + 3X^2 + 3cX + 3, \tag 2$

we have

$p(0, c) = 3, \tag 3$

$p(1, c) = 3c + 2, \tag 4$

$p(2, c) = c + 3, \tag 5$

$p(3, c) = 4c + 3, \tag 6$

$p(4, c) = 2c; \tag 7$

scrutiny of these equations reveals that $p(X, c)$ has a root precisely when

$c = 0, 1, 2, 3; \tag 8$

thus $p(X, c)$ is irreducible for

$c = 4. \tag 9$

For this value of $c$, the ideal $(p(X, c))$ is maximal and hence $\Bbb F_5[X]/(p(X, c))$ is a field.

Comment: Isn't $p(1,1)=0$? This would imply that $p(X)$ hast a root also for $c=1$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger:  looks like you are right.  Let me take a closer look. Thanks